# (−2.8; 95% CI, −4.2 to −1.4; p < 0.001) interpretation

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value

[image]

Hello
Can you please tell me how to interpret this result?−2.8; 95% CI, −4.2 to −1.4; p < 0.001)
And it is normal to have minus values like−2.8; 95% CI, −4.2 to −1.4; p < 0.001)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To get the value, they subtracted group A from group B (B - A). If B is bigger, you'd get a positive number. If A is bigger, you'd get a negative number.

Here, they subtracted stress intensity at the end of 8 weeks from stress intensity at the beginning. Stress went down, so you have a negative number. If stress went up, you'd have a positive number.

If your question is about the 95% confidence interval, wikipedia has a pretty decent explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Meaning_and_interpretation